# 3 column bulk image gallery

Tags: jquery, css

Okay, I have literally searched all over the web, but I didn't find what I would like to create to my page. I would like to make a gallery with 3 columns, with the same width (so the images are resized to fit in, but they keep the ratio, so they heights are different).
What it should seems like:

```
XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX 
    XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX
XXX     XXX
XXX XXX
    XXX XXX
XXX     XXX
XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX
    XXX
```

I hope you can imagine it.
And of course it's important that after all pictures in it (which are read from database), than the height of the columns should be nearly the same.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the order of the pictures matter?

Comment: I think not really, it would be better when the first columns first picture will be th first, the second columns first the second etc, but it's good too when first it fills the first column, then the second, then the third. So the answer: no :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems too hard without using jQuery.

Suppose you have all your images inside 3 div, but in your native html code, you put all your image in the 1st div only.

After pageload-event, you can count the height of the 1st div, then devide it by 3 to get the approximate height of each div.

Then, loop through the image inside the 1st div (using while loop), append the image one by one to the 2nd div until the height of 1st div become smaller the approximate height you've calculated.

Do the same to the 2nd div.

After all you have the 3 div with almost the same height.

That's what popped out of my head. I'm eager to see a better strategy.